# how does the default state get set in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm a beginner in React/Redux, just a question on default state. I saw some code like this:

```
const filtersReducerDefaultState = {
    text: 'Coffee',
    sortBy: 'date',

};

export default (state = filtersReducerDefaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_TEXT_FILTER':
           return {...state, text:action.text};
        case 'Sort_BY_AMOUNT':
           return {...state, sortBy:'amount'};
        case 'Sort_BY_DATE':
           return {...state, sortBy:'date'};
        case 'SET_START_DATE':
           return {...state, startDate:action.startDate};
        case 'SET_END_DATE':
           return {...state, endDate:action.endDate};
        default:
           return state;
    }
};

and then use redux' s createSotre
```

then it tried to access the state by using 'connect' in a component like:

```
this.props.filter.text
```

I don't understand how this works, because the default state is just used by the reducer when generating an action. So how could it set this default state without dispatching an action? can anyone elaborate how 'filtersReducerDefaultState ' get set as default state without dispatching an action

Answer (score 0):

Quoting official Redux [documentation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state#initializing-state) here

> There are two main ways to initialize state for your application. The createStore method can accept an optional preloadedState value as its second argument. Reducers can also specify an initial value by looking for an incoming state argument that is undefined, and returning the value they'd like to use as a default. This can either be done with an explicit check inside the reducer, or by using the ES6 default argument value syntax: function myReducer(state = someDefaultValue, action)

The setup you posted uses the 2nd method of initializing redux state, which is ES6 default argument.
With the initial action being dispatched by Redux, the reducer will get `state` as `undefined`, and as you are using default argument (i.e. `(state = filtersReducerDefaultState) => ...`), the `default` case of `switch` will return the `filtersReducerDefaultState`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see

Answer (score 0):

Redux calls reducers with a dummy action to initialize the state. That's how that default value for the state parameters becomes the initial state.

More info [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state#single-simple-reducer):

> When Redux initializes it dispatches a "dummy" action to fill the
>   state. So your counter reducer was called with state equal to
>   undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. so if I remove the ```default : return state;```, then the default state won't be set, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it will be set to `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The default state is set by initialState. In your case by filtersReducerDefaultState. Later if you want to change the redux state you need to dispatch an action. Initial state is like this.state in your constructor and dispatching an action is like this.setState